# Knight (Chess) Problem on telephone keyboard

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem, chessboard

There is phone keyboard with Knight on 0 (as shown below).

```
123
456
789
 0
```

Knight moves as per the rules of chess (2 straight and one turn).

T is no. of moves by knight and S is sum of key's values where knight moves.

After T = 1024 moves, What will be the probability that S is divisible by 5 given that it is already divisible by 7.

I tried by drawing a tree structure and found that sum S would occur in odd-even pattern in alternate values. I also found the range of values of S after T = 1024 moves. But I couldn't proceed further.

Comment: @RossMillikan we're looking at the divisibility of the sum of the keys visited.

Comment: The even-odd pattern will be violated if the knight jumps back to 0 (assuming that's allowed)

Comment: @n1000 It can't jump to 0 back.  There no possible move for it to jump to zero. It is allowed but there is no possible move.

Comment: At time 1, the position is uniform on {4,6}. Afterwards, one performs a simple random walk on the discrete circle 16729438 and the position is uniform on {1,7,9,3} at even times and uniform on {6,2,4,8} at odd times (state 5 is never visited). But how to deal with divisibilities by 7 and by 5 in this setting is not clear to me at the moment.

Comment: Sure this is solvable mathematically (as opposed to, by brute force aided by a computer)?